# Why qemu execute the bin of mipsel failed?

Tags: gcc, mips

1.This is my mips assembly code

```
        .data
out_string: .ascii "hello \n"

        .text
        .global main
main:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, out_string
        syscall


        li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

2.Then I as the code

```sh
mipsel-linux-gun-as --march=mips2 word.S -o word.o
```

3.I use the gcc link the code

```sh
mipsel-linux-gun-gcc -L /usr/mipsel-linux-gun word.o -o word
```

4.I use the qemu  simulation the mips enviroment to execute the bin . The I get some error !!!

```sh
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

5. Can you help me to compiler the mips code! 
   Thanks!

Comment: That code uses system calls provided by simulators like SPIM and MARS. Are you sure that those are available in your QEMU setup?

Comment: The qemu can't suport the syscall?

Comment: I've no idea if it does support that. So you're going to have to find out. But all the bare metal QEMU examples I've seen do character output by writing individual characters to a simulated serial port.

Comment: Can you give me a url? I don't have any idea?